# GridView in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a gridview of images in android. When i click any item on it, i want to show a new set of items over it. This is the screen shot .

[image]

Can this be done using gridview? Also what should be the type of view which must come over the gridview? The background should become preferably faded.

Answer (score 2):

I am not so sure if you can achieve the second view using a grid view. In the grid view AFAIK you don't have any option of specifying the location of the grid elements. It just arranges it from left to right and wraps around.

But here is how I would do it -

- First view can be done using the grid
  view, as you already know/done.
- For the second view since you want the the first view to remain in the background, there are two ways to go about this -

  1. First option

     - You can use a dialog, you can create your own custom dialog which has makes it translucent.
     - In this custom dialog you can add further elements like images.[Custom dialog example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog). For details on how to make it translucent you can look the sample app in android sdk.
  2. Second option -

     - Use a layoutInflater. Put all your views into it.
     - You can display one view on top of another using the `visibility` attribute of the view. [Layout Inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: Thanks.. I'l check it out.
BTW, can dialogs be positioned relative to the item that was selected?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, would you mind elaborating on it?

Comment: I meant can the position of the dialog box be specified so that it is placed next to the item that was clicked?
Also in the screenshot, the item having focus is not exactly a rectangular box.
Can dialogs have arbitrary shape ?

Comment: I am not sure or rather don't know :) if you can place the dialog box at a specific location. Yes, your dialog can have arbitrary shape. Since you are defining your own layouts.. it can be anything you can design.